# Does Task.Wait(int) start waiting right when it's called, or when the Task starts running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library, wait

This is a pretty subtle question, but my curiosity got the best of me, and I couldn't find the answer in the docs, or elsewhere on SO.

The docs for [`Task.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait_System_Int32_) say:

> Waits for the Task to complete execution within a specified number of milliseconds.

It returns:

> `true` if the Task completed execution within the allotted time; otherwise, `false`.

Consider this snippet:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
});
task.Wait(1000);
```

Does the timeout countdown start immediately when I call `Task.Wait(...)`, or does `Wait(...)` first wait for the Task to actually start running before kicking off the countdown? (`Task.Run(...)` only makes the Task eligible to run. It doesn't guarantee that it's actually started)

For example, if all the threads in the threadpool are in use, and the thread pool has to delay by, say, 0.5 seconds before creating a new thread for my queued-Task, will my `Wait(1000)` call return after the full second, or after 0.5 seconds?

If I were to guess, I would say that `Wait(...)` will return after the full second, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Seems like this would be pretty easy for you to test.

Comment: @JohnWu I created a little test but the results were strange and inconclusive. It wasn't as simple a test as what's in the answer though...

Comment: @pushkin Simple.  Wait on a task that you never start.  Either it hits the timeout and continues, or it never times out, based on which option it is.

Comment: @Servy You mean to use the `Task` constructor and never call `Start`? I'm interested in the case where you call `Start` (or `Run`), but the task is queued up and run on a delay, because all the other threads in the threadpool are busy.

Comment: @Servy Though your example is a little different than what I was intending to test, its result does actually answer my question (see the answer below). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since by my reading, it would be easy enough for you to test the scenario to find out for yourself, I'm not really sure I'm actually understanding what you're asking. That said, here's how *I* would test it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = new Task(() => WriteLine("task!"));

    task.Wait(1000);

    WriteLine("Done waiting");
}
```

And sure enough, if you run the above code, you'll find that even though you've never started the task, the call to `Wait()` will still expire after 1 second.

In other words, just as the documentation says, the method waits for up to the time specified for the task to complete, and then returns.

Given that the `Wait()` method will return even if the task's never even been started, that it will also return if the task's been started, but hasn't been given a chance to run any code yet. It sounds like that's actually the scenario you were asking about.

Whether the task starts or not is irrelevant (though, in practice we almost never have unstarted tasks these days…good idiomatic C# programming practices dictate that you only get a `Task` object from mechanisms that return an already-started task, such as `Task.Run()` or calling an `async` method).

Or look at it this way: if your mom tells you, "I'll serve dinner as soon as you're done cleaning your room, but no later than 30 minutes from now", do you think she'll take into consideration whether you've actually *started* cleaning your room or not? No, she's going to serve dinner in 30 minutes, no matter what.

Same thing with .NET. It doesn't care if you started the task or not, just that it didn't complete within the allotted time.

Comment: Even with `Task.Run` though, all you "know" after calling it is that the `Task` is running *or will run in the future* (all other things being equal). Some other chunk of code may have just hosed the thread pool with tonnes of undeclared long-running operations...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes, I guess it depends on your definition of "started". To me, it's not a question of a thread being assigned from the pool to the task, or even of the thread being scheduled for execution on a CPU core, but rather whether the task is _eligible_ for execution. Until you "start" a task, it's not even eligible for execution; once you "start" a task, it may or may not get to do any work right away, but it's (in my view) definitely _started_.

Comment: I tend to have a [`TaskStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=netframework-4.7.2) view of the world. :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: but, I take your point. I think you're saying that the OP may be curious not about whether the task has been started (according to my definition) but whether it's gotten a chance to run. That said, I think it's fair to say that if the `Wait()` method will return even if the task's never even been started, that it will also return if the task's been started, but hasn't been given a chance to run any code yet. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yes, I'm not interested in when the task is eligible for execution, but when it's actually running. Your example provides a nice corollary to that that I didn't consider trying. "if the Wait() method will return even if the task's never even been started, that it will also return if the task's been started, but hasn't been given a chance to run any code yet." answers my question - thanks